# Kernel module profilers

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, profiler, kernel-module

I want to profile some modules (for example network subsystem module).
Can we profile time / cpu utilization of a function in kernel module?

I heard about some profilers such as:

- [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for system-wide profiling
- [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) -- application level

Is there any profiler to best suit for my use case above?

I really appreciate your time, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that profiling itself will reveal useful results -- you will need to make this function to be called very often or spend significant time in it. Otherwise you will get very small amount of data since `perf` profiles all modules.

If you want to measure real time spend while executing function, I suggest you to look at [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/):

```
stap -e 'global tms; 
    probe kernel.function("dev_queue_xmit") { 
        tms[cpu()] = local_clock_ns(); } 
    probe kernel.function("dev_queue_xmit").return { 
        println(local_clock_ns() - tms[cpu()]); }'
```

This script saves local CPU time in nanoseconds to `tms` associative array on entry to function `dev_queue_xmit()`. When CPU leaves `dev_queue_xmit()`, second probe calculates delta. Note that if CPU will be switched in `dev_queue_xmit()`, it can show messy results.

To measure times for module, replace `kernel.function("dev_queue_xmit")` with `module("NAME").function("*")`, but attaching to many functions may affect performance. You may also use `get_cycles()` instead of `local_clock_ns()` to get CPU cycles.

Comment: myaut, firstly thanks for sharing your view, let me check this once.

Answer (score 4):

You had it right! Perf is the tool for you. Since you're going to profile a kernel module, there's no point in using any userland tools such as valgrind

Usually when monitoring software you care about how much time your system spends in each system, this can be achieved by `perf top` that will give you a good estimate of much of the time you system is spending at each function.

Functions that you're spending a lot of time in can be very good pointers for optimization.

I'm not sure I understand the time / cpu model you require, but I think the above should meet your needs.

You can read more about how to use perf [here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Introduction).

[EDIT]
Like @myaut said, there are other kernel profiling tools. While I have very good experience with perf and I disagree with @myaut about the quality of the results, it is well worth mentioning some of the other tools. If you're just interested in getting the job done perf will do just fine, but if you want to learn about other profiling tools and their abilities, I found this nice reference [here](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/lcjp13_zannoni.pdf)

(...Don't forget to kindly mark @myaut or my answer as accepted if we helped you...)

Comment: > I have very good experience with perf < Sounds like [streetlight anti-method](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2413037), huh? ;) Actually I'm not opposing to `perf`, it is good profiler, I'm opposing to use of profiling in OP task (measure times for a particular function), it is a task for tracing.

Comment: I don't oppose neither, perf worked for me in the past, and I never used SystemTap myself but pretty sure it will do the job just fine as well, whatever gets the job done!

Comment: I found reference given by ishay is useful, thanks ishay